# K-fold validation on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, data-validation

I have a satellite image "india_image" and data in form of a feature-collection "ft". I want to perform k-fold validation on this data in Earth Engine. How to do so?

```
var india_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(india)
    .filterDate('2014-03-01','2014-09-01')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .map(maskClouds)
    .median();

var ft = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1fWY4IyYiV-BA5HsAKi2V9LdoQgsbFtKK2BoQiHb0');
```

I am training a CART model using this data.

```
var training = india_image.sampleRegions(ft,['class'],30);
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, 'class', bands);
```

I want to perform k-fold validation on this data. How can I achieve it?